# JMeter share setUp Thread Group variables with normal Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

Imagine I have a simple test plan, like so:

```
setUp Thread Group
-- Http Request
---- JSON Extractor

Thread Group
-- Http Request

tearDown Thread Group
-- Http Request
```

By default, the variables extracted in the `setUp Thread Group` will not be accessible within the ordinary `Thread Group` nor the `tearDown Thread Group`. The variables' contents are *different for each user* and cannot be precomputed and loaded into the test plan. It is not possible to simulate the correct load using a single user.

How can I access each thread's setUp variables from within the corresponding Thread Group proper and tearDown?

Answer (score 7):

JMeter Variables scope is limited to current Thread Group only, if you need to pass some data between different Thread Groups you need to convert JMeter Variables into JMeter Properties:

- use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) to set a JMeter Property in i.e. setUp Thread Group
- use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) to read the property value in another Thread Group.

More information: [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups)

Comment: Properties are global right, they wouldn't be individual to each user?

Comment: Yes, properties are global for the whole JVM, if you need them to be user-specific you can use i.e. [__threadNum() function](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) as prefix or postfix so virtual user #1 would have one value, virtual user #2 another value, etc.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how that might work? Is there either a performance or coded limit to the amount of properties that can be set in this way?

Comment: Here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/632vw.png. You may also find [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin interesting, it can be used for passing variables between different JMeter threads and even thread groups. You can install the plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks, that's working for 2 threads. I'm still concerned about scale though, what happens at say 5000 distributed threads?

That plugin appears to implement a queue, which would be great for one variable but not for transferring multiple variables, without implementing custom code to combine and split them.

Answer (score 1):

You stated in comments

> 5000 distributed threads..  transferring multiple variables...

Maybe [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)s will help you to save(insert) variable to database and get(select) variable and delete/update variable wherever you are in test.

Comment: I imagine that may perform better, yeah, although it's still alot of seemingly unnecessary synchronisation for individual threads that retain the same thread id (eg 1-1, 1-2) throughout all 3 stages. Not to mention the effort of setting this db up...